# Ajax driven website and google SEO

Tags: ajax, seo, sitemap, bots

My problem is that Google doesn't index my website and it's been 5 weeks that the site is up and running.

It's not that it doesn't index my internal pages, it is that **it does not index the website itself**.

My website "ww.xyz.com" is just completely ignored when you type "xyz" as search keyword on Google.

The website is ajax driven and this is my configuration:

I have a robot.txt in the server root folder:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Sitemap: http://www.xyz.com/sitemap.xml
```

I have a sitemap.xml in the server root folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <url><loc>http://www.xyz.com/</loc></url>
    <url><loc>http://www.xyz.com/index.php?action=link1</loc></url>
    <url><loc>http://www.xyz.com/index.php?action=link2</loc></url>
</urlset>
```

The index page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

    <head>

        <title>xyz</title>

        <meta http-equiv= "content-type"      content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv= "Content-Language"  content="fr" >
        <meta name      = "fragment"          content="!">
        <meta name      = "google"            content="notranslate">
        <meta name      = "robots"            content="index,follow"> 
        <meta name      = "Description"       content="...">
        <meta name      = "Keywords"          content="...">

    </head>

    <body>

        <ul id="menu>
            <li id="mylink1">
                <a href="index.php?action=link1">Link 1</a>
            </li>

            <li id="mylink2">
                <a href="index.php?action=link2">Link 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="content">
            <?php include('ajax.php');?>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

The "ajax.php" file looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#link1').click(function(e) 
    {   
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"includes/page1.php,
            data:"action=link1",
            complete:function(data){$('#content').html(data.responseText);}
        }); 

    $('#link2').click(function(e) 
    {   
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"includes/page2.php,
            data:"action=link2",
            complete:function(data){$('#content').html(data.responseText);}
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Let's assume we are targeting "includes/page1.php", here is the page1.php content:

```
<?php
if($_POST['action']=='link1')
{
    //show the content
    ...
}
?>
```

As you can see, the href url on the "index.php" are of no use as they are deactivated by the "e.preventDefault(); " inside the javascript.

It is the "$('#link1').click(function(e) {..})" that does all the job.

And as the #content is delivered dynamically by using "$('#content').html(data.responseText);",  I believe there is a DOM issue that makes this website uncrawlable by the google bots.

I read this google help page which describes how to make ajax driven websites googles friendly:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

The thing is they seem to explain how to make url's using hashes crawlable by google bots but my website doesn't use hashes within the links so I don't really get what I should do to make my website indexed by Google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your page sample: No HEAD, no BODY, no DTD - no wonder it isn't being indexed.

Comment: Have you ever heard about Routing? I guess this is what you're missing

Comment: Diodeus:I have all of this of course, just not mentioned it but ok, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @metal_fan: can you tell me some more? Your answer is too short to be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Baylock Oh just google for `symfony routing`. There will be more explanation.

Comment: Thank you metal_fan. My website is made of two pages and two links. It would be very interesting to rewrite urls with a big website full of contents but here, my website is as simple as it could be and I just want my website to be indexed. Not even indexed page by page, only and simply indexed as a whole. My website is www.xyz.com and I want to see my website somewhere appearing as a google result when I search for "xyz". Now it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Just a stupid question, you did submit you site on to Google for indexing right? https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1 I think your site should be indexed with no problem.

Comment: I just did it, thank you. I never had to submit anything before in order to have my websites indexed by google. By suggesting that your question may be stupid, does it mean that submitting that form is an obvious requirement?

Comment: Yes, it is an obvious requirement if you want a new site to be indexed by Google :)

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Redo your website to use [Google Crawlable Ajax Standard](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html). But [that's a bad idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).
2. Make your site without JavaScript being required. This is a good idea since it makes your site accessible to both search engines and humans alike. Remember, not everyone has JavaScript enabled. This is called [Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement).

Comment: The site is done and online now. I would rather see what can be done to make it SEO friendly as it is that redo it from scratch. You recommendation is ok if I was in a earlier process but too much radical for a finished and perfectly working website.

Comment: Option 2 wouldn't require a redo.

Comment: Option 2 is more of an opinion according to me. Nowadays, someone not willing to have javascript enable is someone that does accept not being able to see all the web's content. I don't say I'm right and that you are wrong, just that this is a matter of opinion, not a fact. My website is made to be seen with javascript enabled or not seen at all, it is a choice. Google seems to be ajax friendly as long as you get their rules and follow them. The thing is I just don't get them and would like some help to make my website SEO WITH the ajax feature.

Comment: Someone with poor vision and uses a screen reader is not making a choice. It's always been that way. It's not opinion its fact. If you choose to esclude them you choose to limit your success. Every website has to consider this.

Comment: I choose to limit my success as some choose not to display their site on IE earlier than version 8 (its also a choice that reduces the chance of success, but is it wrong?). Your fact is not one if your website is made to show what can be done with ajax, it will be of no use for people not having javascript enabled. And my website is  friendly to poor visioned people as long as they have ajax enabled. I'm not arguing your point, I'm saying I have the right to do the website I want and not having a penalty just because I think differently. Your facts depend on the goals and you don't know mine.

Comment: I don't agree with the fact that you closed the topic as it is code related, documented and as specific as it gets. I feel you closed the topic because I don't agree with you. It was a technical question, you made it a debate on "Why should I not only use ajax" on my website.

Comment: Actually, if you look closely, it was closed as off topic. SEO questions are not allowed here. Just click on the SEO tag and you can see that.

Comment: Who doesn't have javascript enabled?  As of a 3 year old study, even 98.4% of screenreaders have javascript enabled...  http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/javascript-and-screenreaders/